# Deleted old kernels, now can't boot from hard drive or live-usb

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, live-usb, hp

Running Ubuntu 16.04 on HP laptop. New to ubuntu.

When I power on computer, it displays a blank purple screen for a moment. Then black screen with blinking cursor. Then goes to 'Startup Menu'. Pressing 'Enter' repeats this cycle.

From the purple screen I can access the Grub menu by pressing 'Escape'. The only option displayed is "*System setup". Selecting this repeats the cycle described above.

From the 'Startup Menu' I can select 'BIOS Setup', as well as the other standard options. I altered 'Boot Order' to boot from USB device first, before hard drive. I then inserted a ubuntu 16.04 live-usb and restarted. Goes through same cycle above, does not acknowledge the USB.

Last week I deleted some old kernels to free up space on the boot drive, I'm gonna go ahead and and guess I screwed up and deleted too much.

I can provide any additional information needed, just ask.

I've dug around online for a couple hours now and haven't found a solution. If you can help (or point me in the right direction) that would be terrific. Thanks!

Comment: Is [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels/Problems) useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is a button to press when booting to show boot order and select where you want to boot from. Usually <kbd>f8</kbd>, <kbd>f11</kbd> or <kbd>f12</kbd>. Have you tried that? Press it right when the motherboard logo is shown.

If you are able to boot into the live session then it's probably easy to fix with boot repair. There is a guide for installing it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). 
It also explains the option of installing boot repair on a disk. Maybe you could try that?